# creating a configuration pane in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, greasemonkey

I am looking to create a generic config pane for a grease monkey plugin. I was wondering if there exists a lib to make this easier?

I am looking for some tool where you might give it some name/value pairs and it will generate a nice looking UI.

I think ive seen this somewhere but forgot the search terms.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) lib for building pane. Lib is full of easy-to-use visual components.

Comment: jquery ui doesnt really help me much here. what i need is an near-automatic layout of components, not so much the components themselves. ill probably be using nothing more then inputs, textboxes, and checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Given how simple you seem to want it, why not just hand-write some HTML and CSS and throw that up on the page? It's very easy to show a simple configuration window and takes very little effort to make it look presentable.

If you want it to look nice, jQuery UI. You could also try [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/), but the more library you layer on, the clumsier it'll get.

For a simple layout, just use tables. Taboo, yes, but effective... and it IS just a configuration screen.